# how to delete row with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

for that I am filling with a push and also adding an index to each row, what I need is to delete the row.

```
addTrabajo(state) {
    state.trabajos.push({
        vehicle_id: state.newOrdenTrabajo.vehicle_id,
        km: state.newOrdenTrabajo.km,
        descripcion: state.newOrdenTrabajo.descripcion,
    })
},
```

[image]

**OrdenTrabajo.vue**

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped mt-3 table-sm text-white bg-dark">
      <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>#</th>
                 <th>Trabajo</th>
                 <th></th>
             </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="(trabajo, index) in trabajos" :key="index">
             <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
             <td>{{ trabajo.descripcion }}</td>
             <td>
                 <a 
                   href="#" 
                   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                   @click.prevent="removeFromTrabajo({ id: index + 1 })"
                   data-toggle="tooltip"
                   data-placement="top"
                   title="Eliminar">
                   <i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
                 </a>                             
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

**script.js**

```
removeFromTrabajo(state, data) {
    let found = state.trabajos.indexOf(data.id)
    state.trabajos.splice(found)
},
```

The problem is that when eliminating, the last one is eliminated though it is not the one that's been selected. For example: I select the first one, but last one is being deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to pass the `index` to the function. In `removeFromTrabajo` you can directly access the list using `this.trabajos`, check if the item at it exists, and then use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the item at this index by passing a second parameter:

> **deleteCount (Optional)**:
> : An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start. **If deleteCount is omitted**, or if its value is equal to or larger than array.length - start (that is, if it is equal to or greater than the number of elements left in the array, starting at start), **then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted**. If deleteCount is 0 or negative, no elements are removed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#table",
  data: () => ({
    trabajos: [ { descripcion: '1' }, { descripcion: '2' }, { descripcion: '3' } ]
  }),
  methods: {
    removeFromTrabajo(index) {
      const item = this.trabajos[index];
      if(item) {
        this.trabajos.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-hover table-striped mt-3 table-sm text-white bg-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>#</th> <th>Trabajo</th><th></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(trabajo, index) in trabajos" :key="index">
      <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{ trabajo.descripcion }}</td>
      <td>
        <a 
          href="#" 
          class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
          @click.prevent="removeFromTrabajo(index)"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          data-placement="top"
          title="Eliminar">
          <i class="fas fa-ban"></i>
        </a>                             
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it always deletes the last one, not the one I'm selecting

Comment: @Lucas it's actually doing the job but the indices are resetting so you'll always have a sequential listing, the thing that will change is the ``descripcion``. If you want the index not to change, you'll have to make it independent of the loop by storing it in the objects from the start.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing just `id` in an object i.e.

```
removeFromTrabajo({ id: index + 1 })
```

**Live Demo using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

So you should receive only single argument with an `id` and you should remove as:

```
removeFromTrabajo(data) {
      console.log(this.trabajos);
      this.trabajos = this.trabajos.filter((o, index) => data.id !== index + 1);
    },
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it always deletes the last one, not the one I'm selecting

Comment: @Lucas I've added the link of codesandbox. You can look there and see that It will remove only the item that you've clicked

Comment: look https://codesandbox.io/embed/floral-surf-u12k6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Lucas I've added multiple strings and working as expected. Let's say I've added `a-g` then If I click `del` after `c` then It delete `c`. What else do you want?